# Linking tables in SQLAclhemy foreign_keys error [Flask]

Tags: json, flask, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I got two models Post and Category.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    body_html = db.Column(db.Text)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category',
                               backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))




    @staticmethod
    def on_changed_body(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        allowed_tags = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'blackquote', 'code', 'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'pre', 'strong',
                        'ul', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p']
        target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(
            markdown(value, output_form='html'),
            tags=allowed_tags, strip=True))

    def to_json(self):
        json_post = {
            'url': url_for('api.get_post', id=self.author_id, _external=True),
            'title': self.title,
            'body': self.body,
            'body_html': self.body_html,
            'author': url_for('api.get_user', id=self.author_id,
                              _external=True),
            'comments': url_for('api.get_post_comments', id=self.id, _external=True),
            'comment_count': self.comments.count(),
            'category': self.category,
            'category_id': self.category_id

        }
        return json_post

    @staticmethod
    def from_json(json_post):
        body = json_post.get('body')
        if body is None or body == '':
            raise ValidationError('post does not have a body')
        return Post(body=body)

db.event.listen(Post.body, 'set', Post.on_changed_body)

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def to_json(self):
        json_category = {
            'category_id': self.id,
            'category_name': str(self.name),
            'category_url': url_for('api.get_category', id=self.id, _external=True),

        }
        return json_category

    def __str__ (self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

I have successfully linked the Post to their Categories by adding the following to my Post model,

```
category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
category = db.relationship('Category',
                                   backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))
```

which worked great! Now I can choose whatever Category I have for my posts and can see them under their respective categories using `/category/<name>`. Now I am trying to create an API (json) and as you can see from the models with the to_json functions. I created a view to see all the posts and it's info with

```
@api.route('/posts/')
def get_posts():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = Post.query.paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    prev = None
    if pagination.has_prev:
        prev = url_for('api.get_posts', page=page-1, _external=True)
    next = None
    if pagination.has_next:
        next = url_for('api.get_posts', page=page+1, _external=True)
    return jsonify({
        'posts': [post.to_json() for post in posts],
        'prev': prev,
        'next': next,
        'count': pagination.total
    })
```

But now I am trying to create a view to see all the posts for each category `category/<name>/posts/`, so I thought that I need to link up Category TO Post, since I linked up Post TO Category to be able to see all the posts under their respective categories. So I tried to add the following to the Category model:

```
post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```

and then created a view to see the posts under the category as JSON but I get the following error.

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Post.category - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

At first I assumed that It should be a many-to-many relationship, but it's a Category to POSTS so it should be a one-to-many relationship exactly same as when I linked the posts to categories. I am confused as what do I need add or fix to make this work?

Comment: You don't need to add `post_id` to `Category`. That would create a one-to-many from posts to categories, the opposite of what you have. To get the posts for a particular category, you just need to access the `posts` attribute you created in the backref for `Post.category`.

Comment: @dirn how can I access a backref? I tried to google around but couldn't get an answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Given an instance of Category named category: `category.posts`. If you have more questions about what functionality is available, you should [check out the docs for dynamic relationship loeaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders).

Comment: Got it to work by using `pagination = category.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.asc()).paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['COMMENTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)` @dirn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @dirn I got it to work by acessing the backref posts that I have made in the Post class under the category which was `backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))`

In my route `category/<name>/posts/` which is kind of which will look like

`@api.route('/category/<int:id>/posts/')
def get_category_posts(id):
    category = Category.query.get_or_404(id)
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = category.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.asc()).paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['COMMENTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    prev = None
    if pagination.has_prev:
        prev = url_for('api.get_category_posts', page=page - 1, _external=True)
    next = None
    if pagination.has_next:
        next = url_for('api.get_category_posts', page=page + 1, _external=True)
    return jsonify({
        'posts': [post.to_json() for post in posts],
        'prev': prev,
        'next': next,
        'count': pagination.total
    })`

The way I accessed it is by `category.posts` in 
`pagination = category.posts.order_by(Post.timestamp.asc())`